# Apache HTTPS recognized as HTTP in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, ssl, https

I have a Symfony API REST, enabled in my apache production server, which uses HTTPS and certified A+ security by Querys SSL test.

Via a POST route `https://hooks-api.com/hooks`, the API returns a `url` property, generated with `$request->generateUrl` method of Symfony `Request`.
The problem is that the API always generates a `http://` URL since Symfony does not recognize that the server is using HTTPS (tested with `$request->getScheme` & `$request->getPort`).

After some researches, it seems that the `phpinfo` prints a Appache HTTP Configuration with `REQUIRE_SCHEME http`, and all the stuff for SSL is missing like `HTTPS on` & `SSL_TLS_SNI`.

I have created a new production environnement on my own local, with the same virtual host config: it works !

But I still don't understand why the production server does not work... Here is my config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.hooks
    
    Redirect 308 / https://prod.api.hooks/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName prod.api.hooks
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/private.key"
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/key/certificate.crt"
    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'!"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp64/www/production/hooks/public
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/production/hooks/public">
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>
        
    <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/production/hooks/public/bundles">
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: *"I have created a new production environment on my own local, with the same virtual host config: it works !"* - Since the partial config you show works in one environment but not in the other the problem is very likely not in the part you show (VirtualHost) but in the part you don't show (rest of config, apache version, system setup ...). In other words: the information you provide do not actually help to find the cause of your problem.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED ! The problem was that a SSL config was set into a global `default-sll.conf` instead of setting in each VHost.